# Como leer un JSON de una URL

Tags: java, json, gson

Tengo que leer este Json: [JSON en cuestión](http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations)

Para ello tengo el siguiente código y sin embargo no veo el error. Puede ayudar alguien? A poder ser, me gustaría hacerlo con las librerías de google Gson

```
public class JsonUrlReader {

    public BicingInfo refreshBicingInfo(String url){
        try {
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
            BicingInfo dto = new Gson().fromJson(reader, BicingInfo.class);
            return dto;
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Que es BiciInfo? poruq epara que vaya bien tiene que ser un array del tipo que muestra el JSon

Answer (score 4):

Hice un pequeño programa que se adapta a tus necesidades , Espero te sirva :

```
public static void obtieneJson()
{
    try
    {
        //creamos una URL donde esta nuestro webservice
        URL url = new URL("http://wservice.viabicing.cat/v2/stations");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //indicamos por que verbo HTML ejecutaremos la solicitud
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) 
        {
            //si la respuesta del servidor es distinta al codigo 200 lanzaremos una Exception
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + conn.getResponseCode());
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));
        //creamos un StringBuilder para almacenar la respuesta del web service
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = br.read()) != -1)
        {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        //en la cadena output almacenamos toda la respuesta del servidor
        String output = sb.toString();
        //convertimos la cadena a JSON a traves de la libreria GSON
        JsonObject json = new Gson().fromJson(output,JsonObject.class);
        //imprimimos como Json
        System.out.println("salida como JSON" +  json);
        //imprimimos como String
        System.out.println("salida como String : " +output);

        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Saludos